# SELECT BETWEEN to date and two different times in the same date

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

i'm using python and postgresql and pyqt5

my table in my database is like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY  UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            montant DECIMAL(100,2), 
            acte VARCHAR,
            date_d DATE, 
            time_d TIME )
```

I want to select data from this table between (date_d >= 2020-09-25 and time_d > 16:00:00) AND (date_d >= 2020-09-29 and time_d 16:00:00) and how can we calculate the sum of montant column of the same query

the following image demonstrate exactly the period that i want to select

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "select data"? Since you've mentioned pyqt5, it's not clear if you mean it in terms of database `SELECT` commands or GUI item selection.

Comment: well i using a pyqt gui application to see the history of my data but the day in my data is not from 00.00 to 24.00, the day is 16.00 from yesterday - 16.00 this day

Comment: So your question is just about the database query, and is not related to pyqt?

Comment: In the QSqlTableModel the method setFilter use the same query as SQL but sometimes it did not work that's the way I added pyqt

Comment: Ok. For future reference, always try to be precise (and concise) in your questions, providing all necessary details. You should also consider to provide [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying (in this case, the db queries you've used, even if they didn't work as expected): if "sometimes it did not work" we might need to know when it *did* work and when it didn't, and what you did in those cases, otherwise tags that don't seem related to the question will only create confusion in understanding what you're asking.

Comment: thank you very much i will try to do it exactly as you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use tuples:

```
(date_d, time_d) >= ('2020-09-25'::date, '16:00:00'::time) AND ('2020-09-29'::date, '16:00:00'::time)
```

Of course, this includes the endpoints, which `between` suggests.  Alternatively:

```
(date_d, time_d) > ('2020-09-25'::date, '16:00:00'::time) AND
(date_d, time_d) < ('2020-09-29'::date, '16:00:00'::time)
```

Answer (score 1):

As example:

```
SELECT 
   sum(montant)
FROM 
    transactions
WHERE 
    (date_d + time_d) <@ tsrange('2020-09-25 16:00:00', '2020-09-29 16:00:00', '[]')
```

Combine the date and time using `+` and then test(`<@`) that it is in the timestamp(`tsrange`) you are interested in. The `[]` makes the endpoints inclusive. This assumes that `date_d` and `time_d` are `date` and `time` types respectively. If they are `varchar` cast them to the types.